# C++ weird usage of new keyword

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I was trying to learn something else then i encounter with the following code.

`class point{};
point p_;
new (&p_) point(w.p_);`

What does third line expression do, and what is intended ?
Does it helps us to save time while copying or something.
And is p_ somehow allocated dinamically? // I'm so confused.

The place I encountered ->>  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2544.pdf
//Second page of the document.

Comment: Placement new, innit.

Comment: Do some research about *placement new*. [A good book should have it covered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558).

Comment: It does not save time while copying, it does not allocate anything. The example code does not appear in the linked document. Last two expressions could be replaced by `point p_ = point(w.p_);`

Comment: This is a fair question, but the example is very poor. The presence of the `union` is crucial but has been left out.